# Sitecore foreach but order children by date field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I currently have webforms iterating and outputting Sitecore items based on their natural order within Sitecore.

Specs now changed to wanting a datefield against each item and that will now determine sort order by oldest first - whats the easiest method to iterate through but sort the list first by the datefield within each item?

Field name is `EVENTDATE`

Page was currently happy using:

```cs
Sitecore.Collections.ChildList eventItems;
eventItems = eventRange.GetChildren();

foreach (Item eventItem in eventItems) {
    timelineHolder.InnerHtml += "<h3>" + eventItem.Fields["Title"] + "</h3>";
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.OrderBy(ei => ei["EVENTDATE"])` in your foreach loop:

```cs
Sitecore.Collections.ChildList eventItems;
eventItems = eventRange.GetChildren();

foreach (Item eventItem in eventItems.OrderBy(ei => ei["EVENTDATE"]))
{
    timelineHolder.InnerHtml += "<h3>" + eventItem.Fields["Title"] + "</h3>";
}
```

Dates are stored as strings in Sitecore (in Sitecore 8 it's `20171012T000000Z`, in Sitecore 6 it's shorter format). Ordering them alphabetically in fact sorts by dates.